# after deleting and uploading new index html the browser still serves older version

Tags: http, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://d1wktfnq0mcp3y.cloudfront.net/' was loaded

over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
d1wktfnq0mcp3y.cloudfront.net/:1 
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
d1wktfnq0mcp3y.cloudfront.net/:1 
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://d1wktfnq0mcp3y.cloudfront.net/' was loaded 
over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://example.com/myicon.png'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

the problem is that i use CDN over s3 static; but cloudfront redirects http to https; whenver it finds any "http://" in index file it throws error above.

a similar question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286134/amazon-s3-static-site-serves-old-contents) recommended to delete index.html and reupload new file index.html - doing this did not help, as the browser still shows in the "source" tab "http://". what could be the reason?

Comment: You need to `invalidate cache` on Cloudfront distrubition page.

Comment: i did create invalidation and it completed however for 1 cloudfront the error is still there, the old code is there.

Comment: The other problem about loading http resources from https which is complained by browser not cloudfront. This is a securty issue. When loading unsecure resource from secure endpoint. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content#your_website_may_break)
You can test it with disabling browser settings like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59857675/5589820)